# How to run "inhibition of return" experiments online?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, measurement, experimental-psychology, test

Are there online platforms for running [inhibition of return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhibition_of_return) experiments? I want to analyze different cultural groups and an online platform would be the only way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your experiment is possible. If all you need is the cued and uncued times its easy. Users can run an online applet demo provided by [psytoolkit](http://psytoolkit.gla.ac.uk/library/ior/). You can embed the applet in a survey where users can record their times. For more in detail data analysis I recommend that you roll your own based on psytoolkits model. Given how simple the experiment is even starting from scratch should be easy for a computer science undergrad with some experience in .net or another web language.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying now to understand how it works and hopefully I could make something on my own as I need more than cued/uncued times. 'Given how simple the experiment is' is not how I think about this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done quite a lot of work on running experiments online over the last while, and have put together some of the code I've found useful in a project tentatively titled [PsychScript](https://github.com/EoinTravers/PsychScript).

You will still need to actually program the experiment yourself in JavaScript, but with PsychScript you can do this by modifying a template and changing things around a little, rather than working from scratch.

Hope thing helps!

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have to see whether  or not I am able to modify the template. I have seen the OpenSesame Mobile (Beta) app and run it. I wish I could run my experiment online.

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing an online platform to run HTML5/Javascript experiments, recruit participants via email, facebook, or twitter, and collect and evaluate results in real time. Neither you nor your participants require anything but a web browser.

As Eoin already mentioned you will still need to develop the experiment yourself in HTML5/Javascript. However I may be able to help you with development, but please consider that the experiment would be open to the general public then.

Please see http://statode-demo.herokuapp.com/mental-rotation/ for a demo, it does not require signup.

Comment: That's a really nice looking experiment. I've also come across something called [jsPsych](http://www.jspsych.org/), which is along the same lines as what I was working on, but further along, and has a Behavioural Research Methods Paper. Tragically, I had even renamed my project Psych.js before finding out about it.

Comment: I am not able to write to MySQL Database. I wish I could manage this and use jsPsych script.